# Does $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \log \left (1 +\frac 1{\lvert \sin n \rvert} \right) $ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to know if $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log \left (1 +\dfrac {1}{\lvert \sin n\rvert} \right)$ converges o diverges

Comment: The limit of the principal term is not zero. what can we say!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally we have: $|\sin n | \le n \implies a_n \ge \log \left( 1 + \frac{1}{n} \right) = \log (n+1) - \log n \implies S_n \ge \log( n + 1) \to \infty $ . So it diverges .

Answer (score 5):

Notice that $\log(1 + 1/|\sin n|) \geq \log 2 > 0$. Thus, by the nth term test, the series diverges